# Issue with RecyclerView and GONE visibility

Tags: java, android-recyclerview, visibility, cardview

I am having an issue with RecyclerView and the visibility of some views of their CardViews.

As you can see in images 1 and 2, I have a CardView with some TextViews in a RelativeLayout and an ImageButton that onClick, change the visibility of this RelativeLayout to GONE, and set VISIBLE a LinearLayout with a set of EditTexts.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CcKL.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEtt7.png)

The problem is that the RecyclerView is leaving space between the CardViews although they are not using it.

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTeFA.png)

The code of the Card View is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingVertical="15dp"
            android:paddingHorizontal="5dp">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/addressInfo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/checkbox">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/editAddress"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="EMILI BELLOT"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/address"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
                    android:text="Carrer Churruca, 45"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/CP"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/address"
                    android:text="08301"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/city"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/address"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/CP"
                    android:text="Mataró"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/country"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/CP"
                    android:text="España"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/hideModify"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_hide_desplegable"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/modifyAddress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/checkbox"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/modifyAddress"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/nombre"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/black">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/nameInput"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                        android:maxLines="1"/>

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/apellido"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/black">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/surnameInput"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                        android:maxLines="1"/>

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/DireccionObligatoria"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/black">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/addressInput"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                        android:maxLines="1"/>

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/CodigoPostal"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/black">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/cpInput"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                        android:maxLines="1"/>

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/Poblacion"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/black">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/cityInput"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                        android:maxLines="1"/>

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/Pais"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/black">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/countryInput"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                        android:maxLines="1"/>

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="30dp"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/Obligatorio"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/saveAddress"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_white"
                    android:text="@string/GuardarDireccion"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

RecyclerView is like this:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/rv_addresses"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@null"/>
```

And the adapter that control the visibility is:

```
public class AdapterOrderAddress extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterOrderAddress.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<String> addressesKeyList;
    ArrayList<Address> addresses;
    Context context;


    public AdapterOrderAddress(Context context, ArrayList<String> addressesKeyList, ArrayList<Address> addresses){
        this.context = context;
        this.addressesKeyList = addressesKeyList;
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AdapterOrderAddress.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_address_order, parent,false);
        return new AdapterOrderAddress.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterOrderAddress.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String key = addressesKeyList.get(position);
        Address a = addresses.get(position);
        String contact = a.getNombre() + " " + a.getApellidos();
        holder.name.setText(contact.toUpperCase());
        holder.address.setText(a.getDireccion());
        holder.CP.setText(a.getCodigoPostal());
        holder.city.setText(a.getPoblacion());
        holder.country.setText(a.getPais());

        holder.nameInput.setText(a.getNombre());
        holder.surnameInput.setText(a.getApellidos());
        holder.addressInput.setText(a.getDireccion());
        holder.cpInput.setText(a.getCodigoPostal());
        holder.cityInput.setText(a.getPoblacion());
        holder.countryInput.setText(a.getPais());

        holder.editAddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.editAddress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.addressInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.hideModify.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.modifyAddress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        holder.hideModify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.hideModify.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.modifyAddress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.editAddress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.addressInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return addresses.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView name, address, CP, city, country;
        TextInputEditText nameInput, surnameInput, addressInput, cpInput, cityInput, countryInput;
        CheckBox checkBox;
        ImageButton editAddress, hideModify;
        RelativeLayout addressInfo;
        LinearLayout modifyAddress;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            addressInfo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addressInfo);
            modifyAddress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.modifyAddress);

            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            address = itemView.findViewById(R.id.address);
            CP = itemView.findViewById(R.id.CP);
            city = itemView.findViewById(R.id.city);
            country = itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);

            nameInput = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameInput);
            surnameInput = itemView.findViewById(R.id.surnameInput);
            addressInput = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addressInput);
            cpInput = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cpInput);
            cityInput = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cityInput);
            countryInput = itemView.findViewById(R.id.countryInput);

            editAddress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editAddress);
            hideModify = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hideModify);

            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LinearLayout` should have a height of `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`.